# File size validator in angular in a separate custom directive

Tags: angular, validation, angularjs-directive

I am trying to fetch the selected file size in the my **file-validator.directive.ts** but it is not working.

**file-validator.directive.ts**

```
export function fileSizeValidator() {
  return function(control: AbstractControl) {
    const file: File = control.value
    var size = file.size
    console.log(size);
    let forbidden = true
    if (file) {
      const fileSizeInMB = Math.round(size / 1024);
      if (fileSizeInMB < 1024)
      {
        //console.log('less than 1024', fileSizeInMB);
          forbidden = false;
      }

    }
    return forbidden ? { 'inValidSize': true } : null;
  };
}
```

In component.ts file:

```
import {  fileSizeValidator } from '.../.../file-validator.directive';


export class OBCComponent implements OnInit {

demo : FormGroup;
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder ) {
    this.demo= this.formBuilder.group({
      appForm: ['', [Validators.required, fileSizeValidator()]]
    });
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you should call the validators in the form:

```
appForm: ['', [Validators.required, fileSizeValidator]]
```

Also, try to add the type that is return by your function:

```
function fileSizeValidator(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null {
const file: File = control.value
    var size = file.size
    console.log(size);
    let forbidden = true
    if (file) {
      const fileSizeInMB = Math.round(size / 1024);
      if (fileSizeInMB < 1024)
      {
        //console.log('less than 1024', fileSizeInMB);
          forbidden = false;
      }

    }
    return forbidden ? { 'inValidSize': true } : null;
}
```

In your code you just need to pass control in your function:

```
export function fileSizeValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
  return function(control: AbstractControl) {
    const file: File = control.value
    var size = file.size
    console.log(size);
    let forbidden = true
    if (file) {
      const fileSizeInMB = Math.round(size / 1024);
      if (fileSizeInMB < 1024)
      {
        //console.log('less than 1024', fileSizeInMB);
          forbidden = false;
      }

    }
    return forbidden ? { 'inValidSize': true } : null;
  };
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me the alternative of how to call the validators.

Comment: Can you tell me what parameter to pass while calling filesizevalidator in appForm

Comment: Have you imported the validators correctly, it seems you are calling them correctly, but have you imported them ? check [this](https://indepth.dev/posts/1319/the-best-way-to-implement-custom-validators).

Comment: Yes I have added the import. Sorry didn't post in the code. No problem with the import.
If I pass control in the directive as mentioned by you then what should I pass in the arguments while calling filesizevalidator

Comment: I have added the remaining relevant code for clarity to component.ts

Comment: You need to create it as a directive and the  inject it try following the tutorial. I have shared with you in the comment.